# Enforce continuous values for xticks in a bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe from titanic data set which I would like to plot as a bar chart. However, as there are no values for test_df['Family_Size'] = 9 or 10, the ticks for the same are not there on the plot. Is there a way to enforce these xticks on the plot?

```
    Family_Size    0    1
1             1  374  163
2             2   72   89
3             3   43   59
4             4    8   21
5             5   12    3
6             6   19    3
7             7    8    4
8             8    6    0
11           11    7    0
```

[image]

Comment: Add values for 9 and 10 to your data. Then it will be plotted.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : Thank you for the response! I wanted to know how to achieve this by using matplotlib rather than manually adding values to the dataframe.

Comment: Matplotlib does that automatically. But since you're using pandas or seaborn here, the solution would be to add the values to the dataframe.